# I changed chmod to /usr/share/applications/ how to undo

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, restore, chown

I have just installed today ubuntu, and at the end of the day to add an application to favorites I have changed access to /usr/share/applications/ by:

```
chmod 744 /usr/share/applications
```

As a result almost all applications are gone now, I've tried:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/share/applications

sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/applications
```

but it didn't really help. Now I cant even enter the applications folder.

Is it possible to restore everything to the state before I did all this?  To restore my previously installed applications?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: The default permissions of `/usr/share/applications` are 755, and if that doesn't work, you must have done more then that. Anyway, it is easy to reinstall. Be more careful next time.

Comment: You should consider yourself lucky to **not have applied** the `-R` option to `chmod`. Now @mikewhatever's comment should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the permissions to 755:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/applications/
```

I've just tested in a live environment and it worked.